# How to capture Exceptional message on axios post call with 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

I am making a call to a function app which gives me the Exception message if anything goes wrong with status code 500. when i make a call using postmen getting responses as expected .
[Please find this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg4sl.png)

But in frontend by using axios post call making the same call but i am not able to capture the exceptional message.

```
 postMethodAxios = (url: any, body: any, Config: any) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
axios.post(url, body,Config)
  .then((response) => {
    resolve(response);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log( null ,"postMethodAxios - inner catch", error, new Error().stack);
    reject(error);
  });
```

})

The [Response in google console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg4sl.png) after making a call

Help me on how to capture the exceptional message which is returned by the API,  in fact it gives a different error

Comment: I'd start with the [axios docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors). If you use `toJson()` on the error object you'll have a better idea of what is in it. Then you can move on from there depending on what your desired behavior is.

Comment: Thanks, @H3AR7B3A7 i got the solution by referring the above Axios docs